# How to split the string and databind to gridview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string, gridview, data-binding

I need to databind the gridview in which the string come from other system.

The format will like that:

```
A1|Peter|2011-01-01|2012-03-03|0;A9|Jacky|2011-10-01|2012-09-03|2;B3|Chris|2011-10-01|2012-09-03|2;
```

| as separator of column

; as separator of next record

Is there any method to do that ?

Thanks.

my code as below:

```
   Sub Call_Payroll(ByVal SNO As String)


        Dim theType As String = ""

        theType = xxxxxx <- Get from Source

        Dim tList = theType.Split(";")



        Dim dt As New DataTable

        dt = ListToDataTable(tList)

        RadGrid_payroll.DataSourceID = ""
        RadGrid_payroll.DataSource = dt
        RadGrid_payroll.DataBind()

    End Sub

    Public Shared Function ListToDataTable(Of T)(ByVal list As List(Of T)) As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        For Each info As PropertyInfo In GetType(T).GetProperties()
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(info.Name, info.PropertyType))
        Next
        For Each T In list
            Dim row As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
            For Each info As PropertyInfo In GetType(T).GetProperties()
                row(info.Name) = info.GetValue(T, Nothing)
            Next
            dt.Rows.Add(row)
        Next
        Return dt
    End Function
```

Comment: it should be simple if you write your own method to convert it to strong-type/anonymous type object, isn't it?

Comment: the use of ; i.e. semicolon is not clear. Bars | seperate columns data and I suppose, each single string of above format represents a ROW. So semicolon means a Column having 2 values??

Comment: semicolon means another row(record)